# How to emit tap event in react-native at certain x/y?

Tags: react-native

I want to emit a tap event as if the user had tapped the app at a certain location on a view. I believe this will involve `NativeEventEmitter` but I don't see which `NativeModules` to configure the `NativeEventEmitter` with and what events would be produced.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at panresponder: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder

Here is an Example how to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769295/1256697

Comment: I don't see how panresponder can emit a tap event.